# Share data between multiple .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess

Ola there

I run several domains under the same shared hosting account, so I have the following files:

```
/home/joe/domain1.com/.htaccess
/home/joe/domain2.com/.htaccess
/home/joe/domain3.com/.htaccess
```

Each file contains duplicate data (stuff like `deny from stupid.web.bot`).

Is there any way to have a single file that's shared across multiple .htacess files? (something like bash's `source` command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `httpd.include` vhost configuration files (as found in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf` on RHEL systems) - these are preferable to `.htaccess` as they are loaded at server start and not dynamically, allowing `.htaccess` to be disabled and one less filesystem lookup required per directory lookup.

Not all configuration directives can be used in `.htacess` and `httpd.include`, check [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html) for specifics. Directory commands are fine.

Use the [`include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) directive in your `httpd.include` to include a base config file with common rules.

Answer (score 0):

If they just need to have exactly the same contents you could make a master.htaccess and just symlink it into each folder?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the settings for all domains in your Apache configuration

```
<Directory /home/joe>
deny from stupid.web.bot
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a common `.htaccess` file in their parent directory: `/home/joe`.